# Influence of points and coordinates on the KMeans calculation

Tags: python, coordinates, k-means

I'm defining spatial domains with `KMeans`.
But when I use table columns that contain coordinates or the number of each point, it generates different results than when I simply use the values of each point for the `KMeans` calculation.
I would like to know the influence that the calculation of values together with the number of each point results in `KMeans`.

Is the calculation wrong?

Result using the points along with the `data = X = data[['ponto', 'ndvi_15_01_21_22']]`:

[image: Plot]

Result using only the `data = X = data[['ndvi_15_01_21_22']]`:

[image: Different plot]

Code:

```py
#Calculating the KMeans
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
    
data = pd.read_excel("ndvi_15_01_21_22.xlsx")
display(data)
    
X = data[['ponto', 'ndvi_15_01_21_22']]
    
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3, max_iter = 999999, n_init = 1000).fit(X)
    
data['cluster_labels'] = kmeans.labels_
    
data.to_excel('peso_1000_sem_21_22_clusters.xlsx', index=False)`


#generating the map
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
data = pd.read_excel("ndvi_15_01_21_22_clusters.xlsx")
display(data)
    
data.plot.scatter(y='Lat', x='Long', c=data['cluster_labels'], cmap='brg', figsize=(9, 6))
```

I have this doubt regarding `KMeans`. I don't know if the calculation of the points/coordinates along with the points is wrong.